# Responsive design is showing different in different size screens

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am doing a wordpress site in responsive design. Now I have my markup is like this

```
<div class="contact-wrap">
  <div class="contact-number">123-456-7890</div><!--.contact-number-->
  <div class="user-login"><a href="#"><span class="login-icon">Login</span></a></div><!--.user-login-->
</div>
```

and css is like this

```
.contact-wrap {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 25px 0 0 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.contact-wrap .contact-number {
  background-image: url('images/contact-icon.png');
  background-position: 0 7px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: #d4001a;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0 0 0 24px;
  float: left;
}
.contact-wrap .user-login {
  padding: 4px 0 0 0;
  float: right;
}
.user-login a {
  background-image: url('images/login-bg-sprited.png');
  background-position: 0 -27px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: ;
  width: 62px;
  height: 27px;
  display:inline-block;
  padding: 0 0 0 4px;
}
```

Now as the site will be in responsive it is looking with 960 pixel and also with bigger screen but when I am resizing the screen the background image for contact number is not is not coming good. Here is the screen shot for bigger screen.
[image]

Here is the screen size for `320X480.`

[image]

So can someone kindly tell me what is the wrong here. Any help and suggestions will be highly appreciable.

Comment: Well, you should probably convert most of those px values to percent.http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/create-fluid-layouts-html5-and-css3

Answer (score 0):

You could do a negative margin-top on the div - login

Comment: Yes its just basic css code: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/27/the-definitive-guide-to-using-negative-margins/

Comment: You could use css media query's to change the css if the screen size is larger then or smaller then an amount of pixels here is a great tutorial: http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-with-css3-media-queries

Answer (score 0):

I tested the code you posted and it is working fine in all desktop browsers, even IE

[image: test]

Your problem is somewhere around the code you posted, probably some inherited style.
There is a couple of things you can try:

change selector **.contact-wrap .contact-number** to simply **.contact-number**

change <**div** class="contact-number">123-456-7890</**div**> to <**span** class="contact-number">123-456-7890</**span**>

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through the code it is working fine on different sizes of device it's problem would be related to some margin property given on negative and also the other inherited classes.